# android image getting blur after rotation

Tags: android, image, bitmap, blur

when  I call  this peace of code my bitmap looses  quality  and gets blurry

```
public static Bitmap rotateBitmap( Bitmap source, double rotation ) {
        // No rotation specified, just return the original
    if ( rotation == 0.0 )          return ( source );

    try {
            // Setup the matrix for translation
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.reset();
        if (source.getWidth() > source.getHeight())
        matrix.postRotate( (float)rotation );
            // Rotate the bitmap
        Bitmap rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap( source, 0, 0, source.getWidth(), source.getHeight(), matrix, false );
        return ( rotatedBitmap );
    }
    catch ( Exception e ) {
        return ( null );
    }
}
```

Comment: Hope, everyone gets that **peace** of code

Comment: change the filter to true instead of false